# Many of the famous advertising offices are located in Madison avenue

Tags: prepositions

> Many of the famous advertising offices are located in Madison avenue.

I read the above sentence on a TOEFL [website](http://www.yeuanhvan.com/part-2-error-recognition/5862-toefl-error-recognition-test-2) according to it the **in** in the sentence is incorrect. Is the website correct ? If so then what is the correct preposition to use here ? Should it be located *on* or located *at* ?

Comment: I searched on Google Books and it looks like **on** is the more used preposition with "Madison avenue"

Comment: "*in* Madison Avenue" would be in the street (between the sidewalks). *on* (along some road) is better than *at* (a specific location). Also, *avenue* needs to be capitalized as part of a proper name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-place) lists many of the usages of **in, on, at**. In this case the correct choice is **"located on"**. According to the dictionary you can use **on** in the following situation:

> To describe a position along a **road** or river or by the sea or by a lake.